# creating a dictionary from tag texts in xml file (python)

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I have an xml file (see below for example):

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO>7466</DOCNO>
<PROFILE>_AN-CESAXAAAFT</PROFILE>
<DATE>920518
</DATE>
<HEADLINE>
FT  18 MAY 92 / World News In Brief: Mansell drives into the history books
</HEADLINE>
<TEXT>
Britain's Nigel Mansell (left) led from start to finish in the San Marino
Grand Prix at Imola yesterday, becoming the first driver to win the first
five races of a formula one season. Mansell has a maximum 50 points in the
drivers' championship, 26 clear of second-placed Italian Riccardo Patrese.
</TEXT>
<PUB>The Financial Times
</PUB>
<PAGE>
International Page 1
</PAGE>
</DOC>
```

(the actual file has many of these 's)

I also have generated this code so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
from stemming.porter2 import stem as PT

tree = ET.parse('articles.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

myDict = {}
for x in root:
    myDict[x.find("DOCNO").text] = x.find("TEXT").text


for x in root.iter('TEXT'):
    x = x.lower()
    x = re.split('[^a-zA-Z]', x)
    x = PT(x)

print x
```

basically what I want is to create a dictionary where the key is the DOCNO and the value is the text inside TEXT but once it has been processed (which in this case means: converting all to lower case, splitting on non alphanumeric values, and stemming the words).

I'm new to python so if anyone has a better suggestion for how to go about this please let me know! any advice would be much appreciated :)

Also - whenever I even try to print the text inside the TEXT tag I get this weird formatting which I can't seem to get rid of (\n everywhere) - any idea why or how to fix? e.g.:

```
{'8167': '\nTwo officers were injured when police clashed with youths on a Coventry\nestate for the second night running. Four petrol bombs were thrown at police\nvans.\n',
```

Comment: You could try using dictionary comprehension to set your key and values. Ie: `myDict = {i: k for i, k in root if i == 'DONCO' and k == 'TEXT'}` The `\n` represents a new line in the text. You can use the replace() built in function. So in your code it should look something like `x.replace('\n', '')` which will replace all instances of `\n` with nothing. The way it works is `string.replace(old, new, count)` `count` is optional

Comment: hey @Barb the replace function worked, thanks! not sure what you mean with the list comprehension though...what is that example solving? sorry, im new to python still getting to grips with it! thanks for helping :)

Comment: Comprehension is different in a list, dictionary and set. It saves `for` loops and is easier to read. A list comp is like `result = [i for i in #variable#]` which is basically select `i`(something) for that (something) in a path/variable. Dic comp is setting a key to a value `key:value` with curly braces such as `a_dict = {i: k for i, k in #variable#}`. You can then put a condition in `a_dict = {i: k for i, k in enumerate(#variable#) if #condition/variable# in #path/variable}`. There are many different ways to use them. Review some docs https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def _modify_text(txt):
    return txt
    # TODO implement


xml = '''<DOCS><DOC>
   <DOCNO>7466</DOCNO>
   <PROFILE>_AN-CESAXAAAFT</PROFILE>
   <DATE>920518</DATE>
   <HEADLINE>FT  18 MAY 92 / World News In Brief: Mansell drives into the history books</HEADLINE>
   <TEXT>Britain's Nigel Mansell (left) led from start to finish in the San Marino
Grand Prix at Imola yesterday, becoming the first driver to win the first
five races of a formula one season. Mansell has a maximum 50 points in the
drivers' championship, 26 clear of second-placed Italian Riccardo Patrese.</TEXT>
   <PUB>The Financial Times</PUB>
   <PAGE>International Page 1</PAGE>
</DOC></DOCS>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = {d.find('./DOCNO').text: _modify_text(d.find('./TEXT').text.replace('\n', '')) for d in root.findall('.//DOC')}
print(data)
```

output

```
{'7466': "Britain's Nigel Mansell (left) led from start to finish in the San MarinoGrand Prix at Imola yesterday, becoming the first driver to win the firstfive races of a formula one season. Mansell has a maximum 50 points in thedrivers' championship, 26 clear of second-placed Italian Riccardo Patrese."}
```

Comment: thank you this really helped!! adjusted it to my files and it seems to be working! thank you!!